# G-Suite MDM - could I shut down device?

Tags: mdm

I need to find out if I could shut down enrolled device using G-Suite MDM? There are some solutions however I couldn't find anything about that in G-Suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [factory reset a managed device](https://support.google.com/a/answer/173390) from the console at [admin.google.com](https://admin.google.com), it removes all the data from the device.

If you just want to power off the device without removing the data, then I don't think it's possible with the Google MDM.